Installing Metpy on macOS using pip3
I installed Metpy using pip3 install metpy. However when I try a simple example for using the dew point temperature I get nothing but errors. The errors are related (I think) to the import statements. I am using:
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units

mixing = 10 * units('g/kg')
print(mixing)

I am getting the following errors:
File "/Users/johnbarrett/dewpoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .units import (_mutate_arguments, DimensionalityError, is_quantity, UndefinedUnitError,
                        units)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/units.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pint
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .delegates.formatter._format_helpers import formatter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import txt_defparser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .defparser import DefParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/defparser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import block, common, context, defaults, group, plain, system
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/common.py", line 23, in <module>
    @dataclass(frozen=True)
     ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/dataclasses.py", line 1295, in wrap
    return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
                          frozen, match_args, kw_only, slots,
                          weakref_slot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/dataclasses.py", line 1043, in _process_class
    raise TypeError('cannot inherit frozen dataclass from a '
                    'non-frozen one')
TypeError: cannot inherit frozen dataclass from a non-frozen one
➜  ~ python3 dewpoint.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnbarrett/dewpoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .units import (_mutate_arguments, DimensionalityError, is_quantity, UndefinedUnitError,
                        units)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/units.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pint
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .delegates.formatter._format_helpers import formatter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import txt_defparser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .defparser import DefParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/defparser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import block, common, context, defaults, group, plain, system
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/common.py", line 23, in <module>
    @dataclass(frozen=True)
     ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
➜  ~ python3 dewpoint.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnbarrett/dewpoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .units import (_mutate_arguments, DimensionalityError, is_quantity, UndefinedUnitError,
                        units)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/units.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pint
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .delegates.formatter._format_helpers import formatter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import txt_defparser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .defparser import DefParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/defparser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import block, common, context, defaults, group, plain, system
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pint/delegates/txt_defparser/common.py", line 23, in <module>
    @dataclass(frozen=True)
     ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/dataclasses.py", line 1295, in wrap
    return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
                          frozen, match_args, kw_only, slots,
                          weakref_slot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/dataclasses.py", line 1043, in _process_class
    raise TypeError('cannot inherit frozen dataclass from a '
                    'non-frozen one')
TypeError: cannot inherit frozen dataclass from a non-frozen one

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks so much John

You need to include the error messages in the question.

sorry, I forgot the error message, here are the 1st ones - File "/Users/johnbarrett/dewpoint.py", line 1, in 
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/metpy/init.py", line 13, in 
from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402

Edit your question...

This is a known incompatibility between the current release of pint (v0.24.3), which MetPy uses for unit tracking, and Python 3.13 (and has also been reported on the MetPy issue tracker).
The work-around for now is to install and use Python 3.12.
UPDATE: Pint 0.24.4 has been released so that should fix the problems on Python 3.13.

thanks so much for answering my question @DopplerShift I really appreciate it very much. I didn't know about the compatibility issues with Python 3.13. It looks like I will have to figure out how to downgrade to Python 3.12 so that I can use Metpy.

See edit above. Make sure you install the latest Pint, 0.24.4, and everything should work fine now.

thanks so much for the update, I really appreciate all of your help! I installed miniconda and Metpy is working there, but I will install Pint to see if it works for python 3.13. Thanks again!
